# How can I run an external application in Unity and render it as a GameObject in the game?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, external

I've just begun getting used to working with Unity. I'm trying to run external applications from my Unity project. I've found that I can call external applications using the [System.Diagnostics](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa287541(v=vs.71).aspx).Process.Start function call.

Now, what I'm trying to achieve is to open an application (calculator/text editor) within my Unity game as an inter-actable GameObject. I've been trying to look for ways to doing this, but to no avail. Will I have to render it to the surface of some GameObject, or maybe project the application on a plane? And how can I do this?

Comment: This is not possible. Any feauture you want to implement in your game you have to implement yourself or download from the unity store. You can code a game/program/feature to communicate with the calculator for example, but it wont know how to communicate back.

Comment: A complete hack would be to try to set parent windows to a container window inside your app. It would be completely unsupported and there would be no app communication and it wouldn't work on most platforms, and could depend on many factors, so in short, I'd consider a different approach :)

Comment: After giving it some thought, I've realised that what I'm asking for is not possible. Thanks for clarifying that for me.

@AdamTuliper-MSFT Setting the application in a container window within the application seems a fairly decent idea. For the time-being, I would like to be able to simply view the external application in the game in a window. I can understand how the question is a bit unclear on that. Would you know how I can just view an application in a container window? Your advice is much appreciated! :)

Comment: You'd have to make the api call to setparent on the parent window you want to embed the child into or you could position that app via win32 api calls to be in a frame. this approach is not supported however, its a gamble.

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean like calc.exe and notepad.exe? I don't think this is possible.

You want to run a Windows application **within** the Unity engine. As far as I know this is not possible. 
If you can even start an EXE file... it will run in Windows O.S. It will not run in the Unity3D engine. Let alone have it as a GameObject and interact with it.

Maybe you can simply **render it to the surface** like you said. That could be remotely possible. But not to my knowledge at least.

I'm not sure what your goal is. But I think your only options is to **create your own texteditor/calculator in Unity**. (or download one in the asset store?).

Comment: I'm thinking of alternative approaches now.. I'm now trying to render the parent application in a container window in the application, even though the application is running outside of the Unity app. So simply put, I want to view the external app in my game. Any ideas on how I can achieve this?